# Trouble clearing errors in radio button groups using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, radio-button, each

I am using the following code to highlight radio button fields when a group isn't checked and the form is submitted.

I would like to make it so the error class is removed from the label elements of the radio button group that has been checked.

Can someone tell me how to do this by modifying my code below?

```
  checkRadios : function (form) {
    var $form = $(form),
        radioGroups = $form.find(".radiogroup")
        radios = radioGroups.find("input");

radios.each(function () {
  if ($radios.is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr")
           .find("label")
           .removeClass("error");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr")
           .find("label")
           .addClass("error");

    $(this).on("change", function () {
      checkRadios(form);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do

```
function checkRadios() {
    var form = $('form')
    var grps = $('.radiogroup')
    grps.each(function(i, v){
        if($('input:checked', v).length > 0){
            $(v).closest('tr').find("label").removeClass('error');
        }else{
            $(v).closest('tr').find("label").addClass('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dCRaH/2/)

Comment: Updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dCRaH/4/ with change event support

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
radioGroups.each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("input:checked").length > 0) {
       $(this).closest("tr")
           .find("label")
           .removeClass("error");
    } else {
       $(this).closest("tr")
           .find("label")
           .addClass("error");
    }
});
```

The idea is loop for groups and find if there's any checked radio in each group:

```
$(this).find("input:checked").length > 0
```